# How can I get real analog of complex function?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, real-analysis

I have a function:

$$\sin(wt-jT),\quad j\in\mathbb C$$

I transform it to function with real arguments:

$$\sin(wt)ch(-T)+j\cos(wt)sh(-T)$$

The module and the absolute value are equal:

$$|\sin(wt-jT)|=\sqrt{|\sin(wt)ch(-T)|^2+|\cos(wt)sh(-T)|^2}$$

I want to know the absolute value correspond to graphical representation of the function or not?

My output:

[image]

Comment: What is the variable of your function? Is it $t$? When you say $j\in\mathbb C$, do you mean it is the imaginary unit, or that it can really be any complex number? And are $ch$ and $sh$ the hyperbolic cosine and  sine (more commonly written $\cosh$ and $\sinh$?)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a much nicer closed form - the modulus is going to be in the range $|\sinh T|\leq \text{ modulus } \leq \cosh T$.

Note that $|\sinh(T)|=|\sinh(-T)|$ and $\cosh(T)=\cosh(-T)$, so you can at least replace $-T$ with $T$. You can also ignore the absolute values - since you are squaring real numbers, the absolute values do nothing.

I'd write $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{jx}-e^{-jx}\right)$. Then I'd get:

$$|\sin(a-Tj)| = \frac{1}{2}\left|e^{T+aj}-e^{-T-aj}\right|=\frac{e^T}2\left|1-e^{-2T-2aj}\right|$$

The right side traces a circle around $0$ of radius $e^{-2T}$ and then computes the distance to $1$. This will have minimal distance when $e^{-2aj}=1$ and maximal distance when $e^{-2aj}=-1$. So you get:

$$\frac{e^T}2\left|1-e^{-2T}\right|\leq |\sin(a-Tj)|\leq \frac{e^T}2\left|1+e^{-2T}\right|$$

Which can be rewritten as:

$$|\sinh T|\leq |\sin(a-Tj)|\leq |\cosh T|$$

Equality on the left when $a$ is a multiple of $\pi$ and equality on the right when $a$ is an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

It's not clear why your maximum is one, implying $T=0$ and your minimum is clearly positive, unless you scaled your graph.